# Pause the processing inside lmax disruptor?

Tags: disruptor-pattern, lmax

I would like to do a performance test using Lmax Disruptor:

- Configure dusruptor
- Somehow "pause" the processing
- Add many messages to RingBuffer
- "Unpause" the processing

This way I could measure cleanly how fast buffer gets empty. If I "mix" adding many messages (that introduces some delays) and processing I may have less certain results on processing speed.

I do not seem however to find a "pausing" available in LMAX Disruptor (https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/docs/com/lmax/disruptor/dsl/Disruptor.html ), is there a way to make one?

Comment: I'm not sure adding many messages introduces a delay, are you able to explain what you think would cause that?

Comment: You can use this sample :https://github.com/VictorHaydin/LocationTracker

Answer (score 1):

The answer largely depends on what you mean by pause the disruptor.

You can easily have a consumer which does not free the slots in the ring buffer until it reaches the `nth` message. However the time it takes to drain a ring buffer is entirely dependent on the speed of the consumer.

However if you are looking to benchmark the cost of the disruptor it self that's a much more complicated proposition. I'd start with investigating the disruptor projects own  performance tests.

In a bursty workload the disruptor's batching effects may actually improve through put by amortizing the cost of expensive operations, such as network or disk IO.